# Running Alembic Migrations on FastAPI Startup

Tags: python, fastapi, alembic

I am attempting to run Alembic migrations every time my FastAPI application starts up. I am deploying my FastAPI application using a Docker container.

Here is the code I have implemented to achieve this:

```
from alembic.config import Config
from alembic import command

def run_migrations():
    alembic_cfg = Config("alembic.ini")
    command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, "head")

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    run_migrations()
```

However, I am facing an issue where the Docker container stops once the startup is complete. Additionally, I noticed that the logger changes to Alembic instead of FastAPI.

I would like to understand how I can ensure that the migrations run successfully without stopping the container and while maintaining FastAPI logging. Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have your Dockerfile / docker entry point first run your alembic migrations, then start uvicorn/gunicorn with fastapi instead of trying to have FastAPI run the migrations for you. The alembic tooling then lives outside of your app and is invoked in the regular way.

Comment: Yeah I am currently doing this for my docker env. I guess this is the only way to do it now. Simply cuz some of my env are running in IIS, I want a more consistent way to do migrations like some other languages. Thanks.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem recently. I was not able to make it work and ended with the same solution (separate alembic migrations from FastAPI) advised by @MatsLindh

Comment: I was doing it the same way (using mongodb with motor), but the problem is that some migrations take too much time and when gunicorn boots the workers, it kills them if they take too much time to startup. So it may be a not so good idea running migrations on startup event. But you can do it from the shell script which starts your webapp (although you might have to take care no two instances run the migration process simultaneously).

Answer (score 1):

"startup" events are deprecated according to the documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#alternative-events-deprecated.

The lifespan parameter of the FastAPI app is the way to handle startup and shutdown: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan.

You could do this, I tested it with a Docker command that only runs uvicorn:

```
import logging
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI
from alembic.config import Config
from alembic import command

log = logging.getLogger("uvicorn")


def run_migrations():
    alembic_cfg = Config("alembic.ini")
    command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, "head")


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app_: FastAPI):
    log.info("Starting up...")
    log.info("run alembic upgrade head...")
    run_migrations()
    yield
    log.info("Shutting down...")


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck in the same part. In my case, there was a error while running alembic upgrade. It was not shown in logs. It silently terminates the program because of which the fastapi server stops.

Try to run the alembic upgrade head command manually or increase the verbosity while calling upgrade, you will come to know about the error.